# SQL Anywhere 17 - Database server connection limit exceeded

Tags: sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sap-sql-anywhere-16

I set up a new SQL Anywhere 17 Database in Sybase Server. I've got a lot of clients that should be able to connect to the Database over ODBC. The ODBC works fine but as soon as the third user tries to connect i get the following message:

[image]

I've tried `select @@max_connections` and got 32'766.
Also when I execute the folowing statement I get the following result:

```
SELECT 
PROPERTY('ServerEdition') as ServerEdition, 
PROPERTY('IsNetworkServer') as IsNetworkServer, 
PROPERTY('LicenseType') as LicenseType, 
PROPERTY('LicenseCount') as LicenseCount, 
PROPERTY('MaxConnections') as MaxConnections 
FROM dummy
```

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I can cause this problem?

Comment: You seem to have only one connection licensed, so I guess you're lucky that you get two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the dblic.exe utility to apply your licence key to the dbsrv17.lic file. See the docs for details.

Max connections is nothing to do with how your server is licenced. You could in theory set up thousands of connections from one network location, and that would use one licence - you want connections from lots of different network seats, so you need more licences. Alternatively you can buy a core based licence.